# regex: Only match a hierarchical number in python when the whole number is correct

Tags: python, regex, match, hierarchical

in python 2.7 i want to match a hierachical number only when the whole number is correct.

```
my_str1 = "10.2.15"
my_str2 = "10..2.15"
my_str3 = "10.2..15"
```

My regex is:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"^\d+\.?\d+\.?\d+")
```

This matches **my_str1** and **my_str3** (but not the whole one).

As in **my_str2** i want no match for **my_str3**. What do i have to change in the regex?

Thank you.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: think you mean `^\d+(?:\.\d+)*$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also use an end of string anchor `$` that will force the match from the start (`^`) to the end of string.

```
^\d+\.?\d+\.?\d+$
                ^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hZ9mF7/1)

If you need to allow optional `.` + `digits` sequences, use this version with grouping and a [limiting quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit):

```
^\d+(?:\.?\d+){0,2}$
     ^       ^^^^^^
```

You can adjust the min/max values as needed.

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/hZ9mF7/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?!.*\.\.)[\d.]+$
```

You can also use `lookahead` to negate matches where `..` occur.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vV1wW6/29